Why isn't my JTextArea not displaying my string?
This is part of a project I am working on and everything seems to be working fine, but the issue is that the text area in this panel is not displaying the string being put into it.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class movementsPane extends JPanel {
    private JLabel Moves;
    Board board = new Board();
    public ArrayList<String> prevMoveList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> curMoveList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int moveCount = 0;

    public movementsPane() {
        JTextArea List = new JTextArea(100,100);
        List.setEditable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Moves = new JLabel("List of Moves");
        Moves.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(Moves, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        List.append(settingText());
        add(new JScrollPane(List), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        List.revalidate();
        List.repaint();
    }

    public void addListPrev(int hRow, int hColumn) {
        prevMoveList.add(board.tileInfo.get(board.buttons[hRow][hColumn]));
    }

    public void addListCur(int chRow, int chColumn) {
        curMoveList.add(board.tileInfo.get(board.buttons[chRow][chColumn]));
        moveCount++;
        System.out.println(settingText());
    }

    public String settingText() {
        String placeHolder, actualString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < curMoveList.size(); i++) {
            placeHolder = ("turn " + (i + 1) + ": " + prevMoveList.get(i) + " " + curMoveList.get(i) + "\n");
            actualString = actualString.concat(placeHolder);
        }
        return actualString;
    }
}

I have tried putting printing everything there into the console and it worked, the issue is really just the text area.

For better help sooner post a [mcve]

Yes, minrep. And variable names start lower case
in Java. And settingText is not a good name

Where do you actually append(...)  text to the text area? The "append" in the constructor does nothing because you have no data in the ArrayList. Also, why would you iterate through the entire ArrayList after every move. Shouldn't you just add the last move?

variable names start lower case in Java - and class names start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions.

You have to call JTextArea's setText("...") method.

Since List is declared locally to the class's constructor ... how are you intending to update it?

@S.Ashok I believe that method append should be OK.
